# function of object in nested table syntax?

Tags: class, syntax, lua, lua-table

I got a table like this which is giving me

> '(' expected near 't' at 'errorline'

Which means there must be an syntax error, but I can't detect one. Have you any idea what's wrong with the syntax?

```
t = {}

t[x] = {
   some = "data",

   foo = function() return "bar" end,

   elements = {   -- the class is working 100%, have used it for several projects.
     mon =  class:new(param), 
     tue =  class:new(param2),
     n   =  class:new(param3),
   },

   function t[x].elements.mon:clicked()   -- <<< --- ERRORLINE
      --dosomething
   end,
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the function t[x].elements.mon:clicked() ***after the table declaration*** i.e after the closing braces of the table .

```
t = {}

t[x] = {
   some = "data",

   foo = function() return "bar" end,

   elements = {   -- the class is working 100%, have used it for several projects.
     mon =  class:new(param), 
     tue =  class:new(param2),
     n   =  class:new(param3),
   }
}


t[x].elements.mon.clicked = function(self)
      --dosomething
end
```

**EDIT :**

As mentioned in the comments function `t[x].elements.mon:clicked()` wont work.
Function declaration should be `t[x].elements.mon.clicked = function(self)`.

Note that the first parameter for the function would be self if you call a dot function using colon. i.e If you call the function as `c = t[x].elements.mon:clicked(a,b)` then the function should be 
`t[x].elements.mon.clicked = function(self,a,b)`

Comment: mhhh, surely a better style, but gives me '(' expected near '['  curiouse

Comment: You can't do brackets indexing in that function syntax; you need to go the long way: `t[x].elements.mon.clicked = function(self) ... end`